# How much overhead is there in rebuilding a CryptoStream?

Tags: c#, encryption

I've been beating my head over a problem for the past few days: after doing a public key exchange + sign on, my endpoints switch to a `Rijndael` symmetric encryption schema to encrypt messages between client and server.

Problem is, I create the cryptostream and leave it open thinking that that's the best way to go since the channel will be used for sending multiple connections. When I do so, the encryption never completely outputs to the base stream. Per msdn, it says:

> You should always explicitly close your CryptoStream object after you
>   are done using it by calling the Close method. Doing so flushes the
>   stream and causes all remain blocks of data to be processed by the
>   CryptoStream object.

That seems like a lot of overhead to rebuild it for every single message sent. Is there some sort of reason for that, or am I just missing something?

Comment: Be careful: when creating more complex protocols from AES like this; it is very easy to make subtle mistakes that completely break the encryption.
Please use an existing protocol (TLS) instead of rolling your own cryptosystem.

Comment: I thought using Rijndael WAS using an existing crypto-system?

Comment: No, it's just an encryption algorithm. And it's quite complicated to use correctly - even the commonly used SSL/TLS protocols were initially broken due to incorrect AES use (BEAST attack etc.) and had to be updated.

Comment: Do you have a resource I can read up on this? A book recommendation perhaps? I'd like to do this correctly.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology
In particular, I think your protocol as described in your question is vulnerable as it doesn't use message authentication; and you might run into IV reuse issues as well when 'rebuilding' the CryptoStream. I didn't see anything about signatures, so maybe a simple MITM attack would work as well. And given that AES uses padding, you might fall victim to padding oracle attacks.
The number of potential pitfalls is HUGE --> use an existing solution, don't roll your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES(Rijndael) uses fixed-size blocks, so output can be a multiple of the block size. If the input is not aligned to the block size, it is padded. On decryption this padding is removed. To know, how much padding to add, AES needs to know the exact stream length. And that length can be determined when the stream ends (after it is closed).

Comment: Oh so closing it tells how large the stream size is then?